# FTP list of directories only

Tags: c#, ftp

I'm trying to get list of directories from ftp but i'm not able to separate files from directories.

So far i got this:

```
public static List<string> getDirs()
{
    System.Net.FtpWebRequest ftpRequest = (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(path);
    ftpRequest.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(name, pass);
    ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
    System.Net.FtpWebResponse response = (System.Net.FtpWebResponse)ftpRequest.GetResponse();
    System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

    List<string> directories = new List<string>();
    string line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(line))
    {
            directories.Add(line);
            line = streamReader.ReadLine();
    }
    streamReader.Close();
    return directories;
}
```

and i got result like this:

```
folder1
folder3
file1.txt
File2.dat
folder2
```

Problem is, that i never know which one is directory and which one is file. I can't use regex to remove string from list where are dots or something like that because i can simply have folder named like "x.x"

I find way where i can simply create folder with exact name i get from list. (if folder exists i get exception, if not i create folder) but this solution is not good enough for me.

Is there any legit way how to get only directories list on FTP?

Comment: Have you tried [WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequestmethods.ftp.listdirectorydetails.aspx)? You could filter directories from the results.

Comment: I look at Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails but i'm not sure what i should be looking for. This is example what i get with it.

`drwxr-xr-x   5 hexsrv   customer     4096 Nov  5 19:30 .`
`-rw-r--r--   1 hexsrv   customer     0 Nov  5 19:16 file1.txt`
`drwxr-xr-x   4 hexsrv   customer     4096 Nov  5 19:14 folder1`

Comment: You may find info on parsing ListDirectoryDetails here : http://www.copyandwaste.com/posts/view/parsing-webrequestmethodsftplistdirectorydetails-and-listdirectory/ or http://forums.asp.net/t/1476502.aspx?Getting+directory+listing+of+FTP+site+determine+files+folders